# Syntax error when trying to define complex exponential

Tags: python, math

```
def GetE(x1, x2, k, x, z, N):
    firstHeight = math.exp(((k/(2*math.pi*z)) * ((x-x1) ** 2))j)
```

My function gives me a syntax error on the line defining firstHeight. I believe it is to do with not being able to define a complex number with variables, as I have tried:

```
test = 2 + (k)j
```

and also recieved a syntax error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @Guy He's trying to create an imaginary number.

Comment: `j` is part of a complex literal, not an operator the acts on an arbitrary expression. You could use `complex(0, ((k/(2*math.pi*z)) * ((x-x1) ** 2)))`, though.

Comment: Using ``(k)j`` to get a complex number is like using ``(k).5`` to get a float number. Number literals cannot be mixed like that.

Answer (score 1):

`math` does not support complex numbers, for that you have [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#module-cmath):

```
import math, cmath

cmath.exp(((k/(2*math.pi*z)) * ((x-x1) ** 2))*1j)
# (0.998966288513345+0.045457171204028084j)
```

Or you could use `NumPy`:

```
np.exp(((k/(2*np.pi*z)) * ((x-x1) ** 2))*1j)
#(0.998966288513345+0.045457171204028084j)
```

That, and also as @GreenCloakGuy points out, you can't use `j` to convert a non-literal into a complex number. You can instead use `complex()` or `1j`

Comment: That, and also, you can't use `j` to convert a non-literal into a complex number. The `complex()` function can be used instead

Comment: Yes was going to point out too, added to the answer @green thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `j` suffix can only be used in an imaginary literal, not with variables. To get a negative imaginary number from a variable, multiply the variable by `-1j`.

```
firstHeight = math.exp(((k/(2*math.pi*z)) * ((x-x1) ** 2)) * -1j)
test = 2 + k * -1j
```